# Global NavBar in Ionic 2 dynamically changing title

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm using the [Nav](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/Nav/) in ionic 2. I need to retain a global header with a left and right menu. Currently my menu works properly, but I have a small issue. As I change root pages I would like to change the title of the global header, but I can't seem to understand how to do so. I have the following code:

**dashboard.component.html - Page Containing Nav**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
      <button menuToggle="left" start>
              <img src="build/images/brite-logo-bulb.png" width="auto" height="25px"/>  
      </button>
    <ion-title>
    // how can i change the title dynamically
    </ion-title>
      <button menuToggle="right" end (click)="clearNewAlerts()">
        <ion-icon name="information-circle">
          <div class="notice-circle" *ngIf="newAlerts != 0">{{newAlerts}}</div>          
        </ion-icon>
      </button>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<!--Left Navigation Menu HTML-->
<ion-menu [content]="content" type="overlay">
  <img src="build/images/brite-logo.png" width="100px" height="auto"/>
  <ion-content>
    <div class="menu-greeting">Hello, {{firstName}}!</div>
    <hr class="brite-nav"/>
    <ion-list no-lines>
      <button class="brite-nav-item" ion-item (click)="openPage('home')" menuToggle>
        Home
      </button>
      <button class="brite-nav-item" ion-item (click)="openPage('bills')" menuToggle>
        Bills
      </button>
    </ion-list>
    <hr class="brite-nav"/>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<!--Right Alerts Menu-->
<ion-menu  [content]="content" side="right" class="alerts" type="overlay">
  <brt-alerts></brt-alerts>
</ion-menu>

<!--Navigation View-->
<ion-nav id="nav" #content [root]="rootPage" class="dashboard-wrap"></ion-nav>
```

I'm not sure how to dynamically change the `<ion-title></ion-title>` when navigating to a new page.

**dashboard.compontent.ts**

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit{

    // private properties
    private rootPage: any;

    constructor(private profileService: ProfileService, private alertsService: AlertsService){
        this.rootPage = UsageTabs;//temporarily
        this.setWelcomeName();
    }
    /**
     * @name openPage
     * @description
     * Sets the [root] page to selected page from the menu.
     */
    openPage(page){
        if(page === 'home') {this.rootPage = HomeComponent; return;}
        if(page === 'contact') {this.rootPage = ContactComponent; return;}
        if(page === 'profile') {this.rootPage = ProfileComponent; return;}
        if(page === 'usage') {this.rootPage = UsageTabs; return;}
        if(page === 'share') {this.rootPage = ShareUsageComponent; return;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would change your `openPage()` method a bit like this and added a class property title which I would use in template

```
title = 'Initial Title'
pages = {
   home: HomeComponent,
   contact: ContactComponent,
   ....
}

openPage(page){
   this.rootPage = this.pages[page]
   this.title = page
}
```

in template:

```
<ion-title>
   {{ title }}
</ion-title>
```

Or if you need other titles, you can make it like this:

```
title = 'Initial Title'
pages = {
   home: {
      component: HomeComponent,
      title: 'Title'
   },
   ....
}

openPage(page){
   this.rootPage = this.pages[page].component
   this.title = this.pages[page].title
}
```

Possible solution for Tab Component (code is not accurate):

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular'

...
@Component({...})
export class TabsPage {

   constructor(events: Events) {
      this.events = events
   }
}
```

In tabs template:

```
<ion-tabs (ionChange)="events.publish('titleChange', title)"></ion-tabs>
```

In your dashboard component you also import and inject Events and subscribe to titleChange event:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.events.subscribe('titleChange', title => this.title = title)
}
```

Comment: That solves one issue, but one of my pages has tabs on it. So once I get to the page with the tabs, I need to be able to change the title as I tab to different pages.

Comment: well, possible solution is to broadcast tab change with `Events` and subscribe it in  `dashboard.compontent.ts` -> change this.title name.

Comment: I ended up implementing this another way, but this definitely helped with hiding and showing the global navbar from within the child components.